# Loading effect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me with any method, jQuery functions/plugins or so on which can give a loading effect similar to this site http://www.big.dk/??

I'll be loading lots of images and I want to load it the way the site above is doing.

Comment: Not sure if it's my mind, but that link looks incredibly dodgy!

Comment: That's done in Flash, not jQuery. If you can count the number of images that you have, then you can do this pretty easily.

Comment: yes... i know but I can't find any other link similar to the way the effect is implemented. I jst want the first loading effect. The above link is in flash though.

Comment: @blender: the number is not specific. It is dynamic.. could be some 10 to 40

Comment: What's loading them? jQuery or some serverside language? I'm going to try make this thing really quickly.

Comment: @blender: I'm using PHP and jQuery.

Comment: But which one of the two is loading the images?

Comment: PHP. Currently I'm using PHP to load the images and was trying to implement some jQuery stuffs to get the effect.

Answer (score 0):

That site is using a **Flash** preloader to load it's ***Flash*** Object. There are methods, however, to display a loading message while the page loads with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

That site is using Flash. You want to use jQuery. If its an option, the jQueryUI framework provides a progressbar widget you could use to show the progress of a process completing, although its only useful if you can accurately determine the status of the process completion. Otherwise, you could use a spinner animation to tell the user that your application is completing something.